# Get MIN and MAX from an array and remove them for Java

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

I am doing an assignment that requires me to create a GUI for input of scores. I have to then take those scores, remove the MIN and MAX value and average the scores. How do I find the MIN and MAX scores and then remove them from the array?

```
            iaRun1[0] = Integer.parseInt(judgeOneRunOne.getText());
            iaRun1[1] = Integer.parseInt(judgeTwoRunOne.getText());
            iaRun1[2] = Integer.parseInt(judgeThreeRunOne.getText());
            iaRun1[3] = Integer.parseInt(judgeFourRunOne.getText());
            iaRun1[4] = Integer.parseInt(judgeFiveRunOne.getText());
            iaRun1[5] = Integer.parseInt(judgeSixRunOne.getText());
            iaRun2[0] = Integer.parseInt(judgeOneRunTwo.getText());
            iaRun2[1] = Integer.parseInt(judgeTwoRunTwo.getText());
            iaRun2[2] = Integer.parseInt(judgeThreeRunTwo.getText());
            iaRun2[3] = Integer.parseInt(judgeFourRunTwo.getText());
            iaRun2[4] = Integer.parseInt(judgeFiveRunTwo.getText());
            iaRun2[5] = Integer.parseInt(judgeSixRunTwo.getText());

    //How do I get MIN and MAX values and delete them?

    // The average for run 1
    for (int i = 0; i < iaRun1.size(); i++) {
        dTotal1 += iaRun1.get(i);
        dAvg1 = dTotal1 / iaRun1.size();
    }


    // The average for run 2
    for (int j = 0; j < iaRun2.size(); j++) {
        dTotal2 += iaRun2.get(j);
        dAvg2 = dTotal2 / iaRun2.size();
    }
```

Comment: Sort the array, remove the first and last elements, you could use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)) to trim of the first and last elements

Comment: So how do I sort the array? With collections?

Comment: You can use `Collections`, but `Arrays` has a `sort` method as well.  It depends if you're allowed to use `Collections` or not (which are more flexible)

Comment: Is it as simple as;  iaRun1.sort();

Comment: `Arrays.sort(iaRun1)`

Comment: Ok thankyou for your help, I will do some more research @MadProgrammer